# How to give/convert values inside a dictionary in a json file to timestamp values

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

```
import requests
r=requests.get('https://www.ercot.com/api/1/services/read/dashboards/todays-outlook.json?_=1645233254068')
loaded=r.json()
```

I am scraping a dashboard from a website (https://www.ercot.com/gridmktinfo/dashboards/supplyanddemand) and the file there is in json format. So Now I am getting the json file and storing it. But in that json file the timestamp is coming like this

```
{'capacity': 51768,
   'demand': 44863,
   'forecast': 1,
   'dstFlag': 0,
   'interval': 0,
   'hourEnding': 20},
  {'capacity': 51941,
   'demand': 44902,
   'forecast': 1,
   'dstFlag': 0,
   'interval': 5,
   'hourEnding': 20} ) so on......
```

So here I am getting what I wanted like capacity and demand. However, I also need the timestamp. but here the time is distributed in different keys like interval and hourEnding. Also I want to remove dstFlag and forecast from the whole data as they are of no use. So is there any way to convert those keys into timestamp?

And I want to save this json file as a csv at the end.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're trying to parse the JSON at any point, so unclear what issues you're having. In other words, there's nothing to remove, but you do need to extract what you want... And an hour alone does not represent any timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for something like this

```
from datetime import datetime
updated = datetime.fromisoformat(loaded["lastUpdated"])

for d in loaded["data"]:
   capacity = d['capacity']
   demand = d['demand']
   is_forecast = d['forecast'] == 1
   minute = d['interval']
   hour = d['hourEnding']

   ts = datetime(updated.year, updated.month, updated.day, hour=hour, minute=minute)
   # TODO: print csv output
```

Keep in mind that DST does matter for timestamp creation

Comment: ts = datetime(updated.year, updated.month, updated.day, hour=hour, minute=minute) .....getting error 'hour must be in 0..23'

Comment: The very last value is hour 24 (midnight of the next day). You can filter it out if you don't need it